# How to combine multiple dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I used the `pd.Dataframe` to convert multiple Excel tables to dataframes such as `df1, df2`...

Now I want to get only one dataframe like `[df1,df2,....]`. How can I realize it?

Comment: Look up `pd.merge` and/or `pd.concat`.

Comment: Could you share some more details i.e. input and expected output? Also what did you try so far?

Comment: Use this link to see all the options to do this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html